# How to write a polars dataframe to DuckDB

Tags: python, uri, python-polars, duckdb

I am trying to write a Polars DataFrame to a duckdb database. I have the following simple code which I expected to work:

```
import polars as pl
import duckdb

pldf = pl.DataFrame({'mynum': [1,2,3,4]})
with duckdb.connect(database="scratch.db", read_only=False) as con:
    pldf.write_database(table_name='test_table', connection=con)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Expected string or URL object, got <duckdb.duckdb.DuckDBPyConnection object
```

I get a similar error if I use the non-default `engine='adbc'` instead of `df.write_database()`'s default `engine='sqlalchemy'`.

So it seemed it should be easy enough to just swap in a URI for my ducdkb database, but I haven't been able to get that to work either. Potentially it's complicated by my being on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In-memory database.** If you just want to use DuckDB to query a polars dataframe, this can simply be achieved as long as the table exists in the current scope.

```py
duckdb.sql("SELECT * FROM df").show()
```

**Persistent database** If you want to use a *persistent* database, you could install [`duckdb-engine`](https://github.com/Mause/duckdb_engine) and write the database using the connection URI string.

```py
df.write_database(
    table_name='test_table',
    connection="duckdb:///scratch.db",
)
```

Reading the data back in using DuckDB works as usual.

```py
with duckdb.connect(database="scratch.db", read_only=False) as con:
    con.query("SELECT * FROM test_table").show()
```

```
┌───────┐
│ mynum │
│ int64 │
├───────┤
│     1 │
│     2 │
│     3 │
│     4 │
└───────┘
```

Comment: interesting, the first time I ran this I got an error that polars.DataFrame.to_pandas(use_pyarrow_extension_array=True) requires pyarrow>8.0, so I guess they're still using pandas under the hood. I guess with pandas2 and pyarrow it makes sense.

Comment: @MaxPower Exactly, if you take a look in the source for `pl.DataFrame.write_database`, you'll find: *Writing with engine 'sqlalchemy' currently requires pandas. Install with: pip install pandas*.

Comment: Can you do something like `duckdb.sql("insert into scratch.test_table select * from df")`?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor This raises an error about the table not existing. At which point would you try this statement?

Comment: I don't know, I've never used duckdb-engine that's why I asked it as a question.